# Gnuplot: Need the value from a file to plot a point

Tags: file, variables, plot, gnuplot

I am plotting an histogram which resembles a normal distribution. I would like to add a line that marks a value I have in my data to see if it agrees with the center of the distribution. My idea was to draw a headless vertical arrow with the coordinates given by the value. The file looks like this:

```
  Index  Value
  1       5.1
  2       5.3 
  3       5.6
```

I am plotting an histogram for each index, and making a gif with all of them. The arrow would be:

```
set arrow from 'value_index',0 length 0.5 angle 90 nohead
```

My question is how can I access the value with the index that I want.

Comment: Problem solved? Any response would be polite and appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to `sed`, you can read a specific line number with `sed -n Np value_index`, where `N` is the line number.
Line numbers start at 0, not 1.
Then, you can use gnuplot's `word` function to extract the second
space-separated "word" from that line.

```
Index = 2
line = system(sprintf("sed -n %dp 'value_index'", Index+1))
Value = word(line, 2)
print Value
```

With pure gnuplot, it's a little messier but still doable.
The key part is `using 1:(2, Value=$2)`, which is equivalent to `using 1:2` but
it also stores the value of the second column in `Value`.
`every ::(Index)::(Index)` tells gnuplot to read the file from line number
`Index` to line number `Index` (so just a single line).

```
Index = 2
set xrange [0:1] # To avoid warnings about empty range.
set yrange [0:1]
set table $temp # To avoid plotting anything.
plot 'value_index' using 1:(2, Value=$2) every ::(Index)::(Index)
unset table
print Value
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ternary operator (check `help ternary`) to extract your value while you are plotting the line `with vectors` and reuse the value in the legend with `keyentry`. See a minimal example below which you can adapt to your needs.

**Code:**

```
### extract value from a dataset (or file)
reset session

$Data <<EOD
  Index  Value
  1       5.1
  2       5.3 
  3       5.6
EOD

# Gauss curve by specifing Amplitude A, position x0 and width via FWHM
GaussW(x,x0,A,FWHM) = A * exp(-(x-x0)**2/(2*(FWHM/(2*sqrt(2*log(2))))**2))

set xrange[0:10]
set samples 30
set style line 1 lc rgb "red" lw 1.5
set key top left samplen 1.5

set multiplot layout 1,3
    Index = 1
    plot GaussW(x,5.4,0.4,2.5) w boxes ti "Histogram", \
         $Data u ($1==Index?Value=$2:NaN):(0):(0):(0.5) w vectors ls 1 nohead notitle, \
         keyentry w l ls 1 ti sprintf("%g",Value)
    Index = 2
    plot GaussW(x,5.4,0.4,2.5) w boxes ti "Histogram", \
         $Data u ($1==Index?Value=$2:NaN):(0):(0):(0.5) w vectors ls 1 nohead notitle, \
         keyentry w l ls 1 ti sprintf("%g",Value)
    Index = 3
    plot GaussW(x,5.4,0.4,2.5) w boxes ti "Histogram", \
         $Data u ($1==Index?Value=$2:NaN):(0):(0):(0.5) w vectors ls 1 nohead notitle, \
         keyentry w l ls 1 ti sprintf("%g",Value)
unset multiplot
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: I was not aware of `keyentry`. It was introduced in v5.2. Alternatively, for older versions, one could make a dummy plot with nans.